# web cgi in c, serve binary image file

Tags: c, file, web, binary, cgi

i have a cgi program in c, which serves an jpeg file. it works, but i thought it needs fread and fwrite for binary files. can you tell me why it works here for binary file with getc and putc? these functions i thought are only for text files?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n");
FILE* fp=fopen("../protected/DSCN2099.JPG","rb");
int ch;
while(1){
  ch=getc(fp);
  if(ch==EOF){
    break;
  }
  putc(ch,stdout);
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, the only difference between files opened in text or binary mode is, that on some platforms some characters may be substituted (i.e. CR/LF on windows to LF on unix). But you can use all stdio functions on a file handle.

Comment: it is less efficient to read/write 1 byte at a time though

Comment: @ChrisTurner This is not the case, since the I/O is buffered